# separating arguments for a variadic template into different lists?

Tags: c++, templates, variadic

Is it possible to "separate" the types supplied to a class template into different lists so that I can treat them different? What I want to do is something like the following.

```
Class<<A, B, C>, <1, 2, 3>> c; // initialization

template <<List1Args...>, <List2Args...>
class Class {
...
// do stuff on the first list of types
template<typename T>
void doStuffWithList1() { 
...
}
template<typename First, typename Second, typename ... Rest>
void doStuffWithList1() { 
...
doStuffWithList1<Second, Rest...>();
}

// do stuff on the second list of types
template<typename T>
void doStuffWithList2() { 
...
}
template<typename First, typename Second, typename ... Rest>
void doStuffWithList2() { 
...
doStuffWithList2<Second, Rest...>();
}
};
```

As a slight aside, what are good resources/books where I can learn more about c++ 11 template metaprogramming?

Comment: What's the actual use case?

Comment: The short version: to have the types in the 2 lists to be treated differently.

I'm trying to use variadic templates to generate the repetitive code that populates an std::map<std::string, std::function>; a registry. The std::string is the string representation of the type being passed to the template using boost.type_index. Different types of functions are added based on the type. This is to add serialization for EntityX, an entity systems framework for game development.

Comment: If you're constructing code from data then I think runtime polymorphism using a factory is as far as you can go isn't it?

Comment: can you post some example client code, i.e. the code that you envisage will be placing values into this registry. it's difficult to visualise what you're trying to achieve from the example above

Comment: https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/2138237/example.txt
The library I use doesn't have a way of returning a list of all components an entity has, so I use the class template arguments to test which components in that list are present. Right now, all types of components are being treated the same way. But some components need to be serialized differently, which is why I wanted a way of specifying 2 lists of types.

Answer (score 0):

You may use `std::tuple` and `std::integer_sequence` to group types/values.

```
template <typename Tuple, typename Sequence> class Class;

template <typename ...Ts, std::size_t ...Is>
class Class<std::tuple<Ts...>, std::index_sequence<Is...>>
{
    //...
};
```

[Live example](http://ideone.com/fDsdDF)

Comment: @victorious: I declare a type taking 2 template parameters (which are types). then I specialize it for aggregate type `std::tuple` (which is a *list* of types) with `std::index_sequence` (which is a *list* of values).